# Find unique values of a vector with same order as in the vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, unique

I have a vector A=[2,5,6,2,4,13,34,3,34]. I want to find a unique value of this vector but not in sorted order! I searched in Matlab site and I found this function

```
[C, ia, ic] = unique(A,'rows','stable')
```

but this function is not recognized in Matlab R2011a ! probably this function works on version higher than 2011 !! anybody knows how can I find the unique values of A  with the same order as in A like : 
A=[2,5,6,4,13,34,3]

Comment: So what is the error? I suspect you are wrong in assuming that your version doesn't support this. The `'rows'` is not something you would want in a vector.

Comment: Why do you have `rows`? The sample `A` is just one-columned. Are you working with 2D arrays?

Comment: @knedlsepp In older Matlab versions the result of `unique` is sorted, not in original order

Comment: @LuisMendo: I did have a look at the [changelog](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility) and could only find changes in 2013 and 2006. The 2013 changes don't have anything to do with `'stable'`. So I suspect that the 2011 version should be able to handle `'stable'`. I think it could handle `'stable'` back in 2007 when I started using it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @knedlsepp R2010b doesn't support it

Comment: @LuisMendo: Ok, so I **was** wrong. :-)

Comment: As I mentioned before R2011a doesn't support it as well

Comment: @user3185893 Well I don't have access to 2011a version, but curious if it allows - `unique(A,'rows','first')`, could you test that out? Might be interesting to keep that info.

Comment: @Divakar, Nope! unique(A,'rows','first') doesn't work in a proper way ! It sorted the unique values

Comment: @user3185893 Haha no of course it would sort it! But I meant if that is supported (i.e. if it works without throwing any error), because I am using it in my solution, so I had to make sure that I am not providing any "invalid" answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a *vector* (so the `'rows'` version makes no sense), here's a solution based on [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
[~, ind] = max(bsxfun(@eq, A, A.'));
ind = ind(ind>=1:numel(ind));
C = A(ind);
```

*How it works*: Do all pairwise comparisons between elements (`bsxfun(@eq, A, A.')`). For each element, find the index of the first equal element (`[~, ind]=max(...)`). If that index is smaller than the current position (that is, if there's a previous element which is equal to the current one), disregard it (`ind = ind(ind>=...`). Use the surviving indices to generate the result (`C = A(ind)`).

Comment: Isn't `sort` stable in all versions? This would be a lot more efficient. (To use the second output of `sort` and ...)

Comment: @knedlsepp `sort` is stable, yes. But I don't see how that replaces my use of `bsxfun`. It probably can be done, but with a different approach. It looks interesting; maybe post an answer yourself?

Comment: Good use with the `bsxfun`!

Comment: Just curious, does it get `ia` and `ic`? Not asking to modify though if it doesn't, just curious about it.

Comment: @Divakar Your `ia` is my `ind` after my first line. Your `ic` is similar to my `ind` after my second line, but not the same

Comment: @LuisMendo Sweet! But not for `'rows'`, right? That could be easy with `unique(..'rows')` there, if it doesn;t.

Comment: @Divakar Well, my method just doesn't work for `'rows'`. Not sure I'm following you here, though :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah that's what I meant if this will handle `'rows'` case.

Comment: @Divakar Oh, I see. No, it doesn't. The question was confusing because it's titled "Find unique values of a vector" but then uses `'rows'`

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation if you are working with 2D arrays and would like to get the same functionality as `unique(A,'rows','stable')` -

```
function [C, ia, ic] = unique_rows_stable(A)

[unqmat_notinorder,row_ind,labels] = unique(A,'rows','first');

[ia,ordered_ind] = sort(row_ind);

C = unqmat_notinorder(ordered_ind,:);

[~,ic] = ismember(labels,ordered_ind);
%// Or [ic,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq,ordered_ind,labels'))

return;
```

Comment: Good one. (Although I have the feeling that the OP will probably answer: *It doesn't work*. ;-) )

Comment: As I suspected the OP choose the *works-at-first-try* solution instead of this beauty. In another story: I think we could get rid of the `ismember` by something like this: `invOrder(ordered_ind) = 1:length(ordered_ind); ic = invOrder(labels);`

Comment: @knedlsepp That suggestion works! Thank you! Yeah let it be as it is, as Vladmir already done that.  Might add `bsxfun` there though :)

Comment: You sure do love your `bsxfun`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
A=[2,5,6,2,4,13,34,3,34];
[B, ia] = sort(A);     % B = A(ia)
ib(ia) = 1:length(B);  % A = B(ib)
[C, ic] = unique(B);   % C = B(ic)
D = B(ib(ic));         % unsorted unique values
```

Comment: Good use of `indexing` at the end!