# Remove non-unique chars from string in MATLAB/octave

Tags: string, octave

Let some variable is string `abac`, for example:

```
un =
{
  [1,1] = abac
}
```

I need to transform it to just `abc`, i.e. remove 3d symbol `a`.
I have no ideas how to make it easy whithout great perversion with string octave functions. Any ideas?

Comment: [shortest answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59641/45297)

Comment: OK, the shortest one is just `unique`:)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `stable` option in `unique`, so the results are always sorted. I was actually working on a longer non-set version for the code golf. I'll ungolf it and post.

Comment: @beaker, I know, but OP never said anything about keeping the order...

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good point... Andremoniy, is it okay that the unique symbols in the string come out sorted?

Comment: Here's a custom one but for unique rows with `stable` option implemented - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28648713/3293881

Comment: @Divakar Oooh, you should golf that... ;)

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the `stable` option is present in MATLAB, but not in Octave.  You should consider removing the MATLAB tag in this case.

Comment: Yeah, guys, it would be nice if symbols are sorted!

Comment: @AndrasDeak I still don't undestand, how to apply this answer...

Comment: @Andremoniy - The answer Andras linked is in MATLAB so yes it doesn't apply to your problem.... which thus leads back to my previous comment.

Comment: @Andremoniy  `unique(un{})`

Comment: @beaker great! this should be the answer +1 and accepted!

Comment: @rayryeng my feeling is that this could be helpful QA in case with strings. But as you consider better

Comment: @Andremoniy - I'll leave it.  However, please be cognizant of the fact that you tagged your question as MATLAB, but this is Octave specific behaviour.  When asking for Octave specific questions, only tag as Octave.  Only use MATLAB if your question can be solved using both platforms.

Comment: @rayryeng no problem, thanks for notice, I've removed tag `MATLAB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find unique symbols in a single string within a cell array, use `unique`:

```
un =
{
  [1,1] = abac
  [1,2] = asdlfkjasdf
}

>> unique(un{1})
ans = abc
>> unique(un{2})
ans = adfjkls
```

To find the unique elements of all of the strings at once, use `cellfun` in conjunction with `unique`:

```
>> cellfun(@unique,un,'UniformOutput',false)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = abc
  [1,2] = adfjkls
}
```

Note that by default `unique` sorts the elements of the result, and unlike Matlab, Octave does not have a `stable` option to turn off this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the unique characters in the order they appear on the original string, the answer is still to `unique` but you need its second argument which returns the first (or last) index of each element.

```
octave> charv = "aaccbbahbc"
charv = aaccbbahbc
octave> [~, i] = unique (charv, "first")
i =

   1   5   3   8

octave> charv(sort (i))
ans = acbh
```

or in a single line:

```
octave> charv(sort (nthargout (2, @unique, charv, "first")))
ans = acbh
```

If you have many strings in a cell array, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
octave> charcv = {"aaccbbahbc", "erfyergfas"}
charcv = 
{
  [1,1] = aaccbbahbc
  [1,2] = erfyergfas
}
octave> [~, i] = cellfun (@unique, charcv , {"first"}, "UniformOutput", false)
i = 
{
  [1,1] =

     1   5   3   8

  [1,2] =

      9    1    3    7    2   10    4

}
octave> i = cellfun (@sort, i, "UniformOutput", false)
i = 
{
  [1,1] =

     1   3   5   8

  [1,2] =

      1    2    3    4    7    9   10

}
octave> cellfun (@subsref, charcv, num2cell (struct ("type", "()", "subs", num2cell (i))), "UniformOutput", false)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = acbh
  [1,2] = erfygas
}
```